# i can not figure out how to implement search engine into sql syntax

Tags: php, sql

```
foreach($dbh->query  ('SELECT a.tovar = '$users_input',
( select sum(b.kusy) from jednotypredaj as b where b.tovar=a.tovar and b.co="prijem" ) as prijem_ks,
( select sum(c.kusy) from jednotypredaj as c where c.tovar=a.tovar and c.co="predaj" ) as predaj_ks
FROM jednotypredaj  as a GROUP BY a.tovar ORDER by predaj_ks DESC') as $row)
```

I can not find reason why `'SELECT a.tovar = '$users_input'`, does not work for my search engine.

Comment: That syntax is not valid in SQL.  Hence, it is entirely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What are you trying to achieve? What do you expect this query to retrieve and what do you get instead? What errors occur? btw your query is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com). Please use parameterized queries instead of inserting user input directly into your statement!

Comment: ok i have  a sql syntax which is working corectly its  this one - foreach($dbh->query  ('SELECT a.tovar = '$users_input',
( select sum(b.kusy) from jednotypredaj as b where b.tovar=a.tovar and b.co="prijem" ) as prijem_ks,
( select sum(c.kusy) from jednotypredaj as c where c.tovar=a.tovar and c.co="predaj" ) as predaj_ks
FROM jednotypredaj  as a GROUP BY a.tovar ORDER by predaj_ks DESC') as $row)  and i am trying to implament there search engine which could use user to search data and i do not know how to implament it . thanks a lot

Comment: Your a.tovar = '$users_input' should be placed in a where clause and not the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you
But do not know how to really use it my whole code looks like this`

```
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="kintrogorgo";  
$password="password";  

$db = "jednoty";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query  ('SELECT a.tovar ,
( select sum(b.kusy) from jednotypredaj as b where b.tovar=a.tovar and b.co="prijem" ) as prijem_ks,
( select sum(c.kusy) from jednotypredaj as c where c.tovar=a.tovar and c.co="predaj" ) as predaj_ks
FROM jednotypredaj  as a GROUP BY a.tovar ORDER by predaj_ks DESC') as $row)
 {  

echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['tovar'] . "</td>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['prijem_ks']. "</td>";  //Tu by mali bit predane kusy
echo "<td>" . $row['predaj_ks'] . "</td>";  

echo "<td>" . ($row['predaj_ks']-$row['prijem_ks'] . "</td>");
echo '<td><a href="3edit.php?tovar=' . $row['tovar'] . '">Zobraziť</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";   
}  


?>  `
```

And i would like to add here search engine to be able search in any row.
thank s you